# How can I solve this issue in C# Unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Here is my function:

```
public void PowerupCollected(int AddScore)
{
    score += AddScore;
    scoreGUI.text = "lol"+score;
}
```

Here is how I call that function:

```
if(other.gameObject.name == "Powerup(Clone)")
{
    control.PowerupCollected();
}
```

here is the error message

> error CS1501: No overload for method `PowerupCollected' takes 0 arguments

What is wrong? Is it because I don't include `AddScore` when in brackets when I call the function?

Comment: Have you _ever_ read your error message? If so, read one more time.

Comment: *is it because I don't include AddScore when in brackets when I call the function* Answer is Yes.

Comment: you can also declare the function like this: **public void PowerupCollected(int AddScore = 0){}** so that the argument becomes optional

Comment: Another instance of programmer not being able to read: No overload for method `PowerupCollected' takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 1):

Either add the AddScore argument to your call (say     `control.PowerupCollected(42);` or make the argument optional: `public void PowerupCollected(int AddScore = 0)`.

Since second solution doesn't make sense in your case, i'd use first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your function call should include the amount of score you want to add:

```
if(other.gameObject.name == "Powerup(Clone)")
{
    control.PowerupCollected();
}
```

should be (for example):

```
if(other.gameObject.name == "Powerup(Clone)")
{
    control.PowerupCollected(10);
}
```

This would add 10 to your score.

Comment: Thank you guys! Both did the work.

Comment: If you found one of our answers to be correct, accept that answer as the correct answer to this question :)